# How do i access this javascript value?

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql, node.js

I'm getting a javascript error returned from postgres using node 'pg'.

Here is the code the generates the error

How the object is generated.

```
function storeDeviceState(ingres_id, info) {
        var deviceId;
        var insertDevice = client.query({
                text: "INSERT INTO devices (serialNumber, imeiNumber) VALUES ($1, $2)",
                values: [info.serialNumber, info.imeiNumber]
        }, function (error, results) {
                if (error) {
                        // [error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "devices_serialnumber_key"
                        console.log(error);
                } else {
                        deviceId = results.rows[0].id;
                        console.log(results);
                }
        });
}
```

Below is a copy and paste of what I see in the console as a result of `console.log(error);`

```
{ [error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "devices_serialnumber_key"]
  length: 130,
  name: 'error',
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '23505',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  file: 'nbtinsert.c',
  line: '300',
  routine: '_bt_check_unique' }
```

Here's what I've tried,

```
error[0];
error[0].error;
error.error;
```

I can access the code for example by

```
error.code;
```

Here are the results of JSON.stringify on the object.

```
{"length":130,"name":"error","severity":"ERROR","code":"23505","file":"nbtinsert.c","line":"300","routine":"_bt_check_unique"}
```

Please help!

Comment: well first off, that is not a valid JSON object

Comment: that isn't a valid JS object, btw. (oh 20 seconds too late) =)

Comment: Are you 100% sure this is what pg returns? It does not look like correctly formatted JSON. Mainly the first square bracket should not be where it is. http://www.json.org/

Ops, too late ;)

Comment: That totally looks as if the server side errors out while trying to generate a JavaScript (JSON) object.

Comment: where do you see this error? on console? if so, maybe that is an object with a weird toString()? more details, please! seems interesting^^

Comment: @Ege more info included in edit

Comment: ...and that is the exact output on the console? Could you please use JSON.stringify on the object directly? maybe that helps.

Comment: @Ege, yes that is the exact output. I've included the results of JSON.stringify in the OP

Comment: @Ege, the answer to the question is to use `error.toString();` lol!

Comment: well... interesting. glad you could find out what is going on =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question was very simple.

```
error.toString();
```

False alarm.

Comment: If someone else wants to answer this for me, I'll accept their answer.

Comment: self answers are fine. Instead, if you like, we can delete the entire question.

Comment: I'll leave it up there and accept my own answer in a couple of days.